# How can I cover the Exception in this code in Test coverage(test class)? I did everything but my knowledge is not enough please help me :(

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

```
public with sharing class SampleClass {//EV GS R-3209 07122021
    @AuraEnabled 
    public static String insertCase() {

        String mReqRTid = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('SampleDevName').getRecordTypeId();


        Case newCase = new Case();
        newCase.RecordTypeId = mReqRTid;    
        newCase.createdByUI__c = true;
        try  {
            insert newCase;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            AuraHandledException e2 = new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
            e2.setMessage(e.getMessage());
            throw e2;
        }


        return newCase.Id;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your unit test, create a user that doesn't have access to the record type, then use System.runAs to call that code.  This should throw a DML exception.